# How to show Unicode characters in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

My language is Persian and I use unicode UTF-8 to save pages.
I transfer files from one system to another.Now I have problem with pages.I could not see text right.

Here is some code:

```
if (ClsTch.IsGradeLock)
     Gnr.AddCell(r, ClsTch.EvaluationFormList.GetStat().ScoreText);
else
     Gnr.AddCell(r, "ÈÓÊå äÔÏå");
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You cannot  see the text right where? In your app? Or in visual studio?

Comment: You don't mean "characters in .NET" you mean "characters in the Visual Studio IDE".  It's completely different.  The former means the characters are showing up incorrectly in an application you've written...the latter means they're incorrect in the development environment.

Comment: @rory.ap you said right.

Comment: @Milney In visual Studio

Comment: JUST change the second windows language settings to Persian.

Comment: @Nofuzy Could You Please explain more Your solution? Because I Have Persian in The Language Bar.

Comment: As far as I understand your problem, you can find solution by tools => Options => Tex Editor => General and check auto-detect utf-8 encoding without signature

Comment: go to `Control Panel` -> `Region and Language` -> in `Format` tab change `Format` to `Persian` then in `Administrative` tab click on `change system locale` button and set it to `Persian`. Then Restart your system.

Comment: Pretty unusual in C#, seems like the file is missing the BOM.  But then we can't tell if you used VS to create the file.  Fixable with Notepad, File > Open > set Encoding = utf8 and select the file.  Verify that the text now looks good.  File > Save As > set encoding = utf8.  And do check if whatever tool you used to create the file has an option to save with the BOM (aka "signature"), you'll need it.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm also agree with you, it maybe the BOM. But Notepad++ will be easier than normal notepad ;)

Comment: @Nofuzy Your solution worked(Control Panel -> Region and Language -> in Format tab change Format to Persian then in Administrative tab click on change system locale button and set it to Persian. Then Restart your system).Thanks

Comment: @Nofuzy put your solution in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to `Control Panel` -> `Region and Language` -> in `Format` tab, change `Format` to `Persian`; then in `Administrative` tab, click on `change system locale` button and set it to `Persian`. Then Restart your system.